# which database supports concurrent multiple read and write without the need of building separate replicated environments

Tags: relational-database

which database product supports concurrent multiple read and write without the need of building separate replicated environments and what are the alternative to achive the same.
Is replicating the environment heavy on resources ?

Thanks

Comment: Um... just about all of them support this. Not much of a point of having an RDBMS otherwise. Can you focus your question? It is very broad as it stands.

Comment: @Oded: well some DBMS are limited when it comes to concurrent read *and* writes. Older SQL Server or DB2 versions would incur very restrictive locks on tables why they are changed - even with inserts. MySQL when using MyISAM doesn't shine in this area as well, so the question is not that senseless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Without more information about the expected load on the system, it _is_ senseless.

Comment: @Oded: not necessarily. If this is an architectural question like "Does an UPDATE block a SELECT on the table?". If that is the case the load is not that relevant because the underlying system will never be able to cope even with the smallest load in a decent manner

Answer (score 1):

When using "up-to-date" versions, any DBMS will support that.

In Oracle and PostgreSQL a reader is never blocked if that is what you are referring to.

For SQL Server you will need to have at least version 2005 to get rid of some nasty locking behaviour.

DB2 offers a "readers are never blocked" mode starting with 9.7

For MySQL you will have to use InnoDB as MyISAM will greatly reduce the concurrency when reading and writing (apart from all the other problems that MyISAM has)

If you are more referring to a performance problem, that heavy writes will slow down other queries, then this is more of a hardware problem than a real DBMS problem. The most limiting factor (especially for large databases) is IO. Using high-end RAID systems (or solid state disks like FusionIO) this problem can be addressed as well - but that will be costly.

Comment: Thanks Oded & "horse with no name !!" 

The expected load varies from 3000 to 5000 users for read and aroud 200 to 300 user/applications for write

Comment: Thanks Oded & "a horse with no name !!" The expected load varies from 3000 to 5000 users for read and aroud 200 to 300 user/applications for write.

The main issue here is selecting a RDBMS for high performance, to put it straight how DB2 can address this proble. It clear from one of the above responsed that DB2 9.7 that "readers are never blocked" but what if concurrent write is required. Can the same be achieved withod building separate replicated environments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure DB2 (with the right hardware) can easily cope with that load. What exactly do you mean with "concurrent write"? DB2 (as all other DBMS nowadays) does a row level locking. So if two processes update two different rows, that's not a problem. Of course only one transaction (process) at a time can update one specific row.